# hibernate issue when cascading entities from a relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, cascade

I made my self a little hibernate sandbox to understand how it works.
I ve done quite well so far with all the basics. Everything works as expected.
I only have an unsolved issue.

To make it short, I have a Rats entity and a Sickness entity.
A Rat can have a single Sickness.
The association is correctly set into the DB and the entities files include this part:

in Rats class:
[...]

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY )
@Cascade({ CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE, CascadeType.DELETE})
@JoinColumn(name = "Sickness_Id")
public Sickness getSickness() {
    return this.sickness;
}
```

[...]

in Sickness class:
[...]

```
  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "sickness")
      @Cascade({ /*CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE,*/ CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH})
        public Set<Rats> getRatses() {
            return this.ratses;
        }
```

[...]

If I create a new Rats with a new Sickness and save the Rats, the cascade works as expected and the Sickness is automatically added to the DB too.
Deletion part works too, when I delete a Rats, its sickness is deleted.

What does not work is trying to create a Sickness and try to spread it to many Rats via its SetRatses method:

```
String sick_name2 = "Tourista";
System.out.println("\nsetting new sickness: " + sick_name2 + " and assigning it to all rats");
                Sickness sickness2 = new Sickness();
                sickness2.setNom(sick_name2);

                 ArrayList<Rats> sickratsList =  (ArrayList<Rats>) session.createCriteria(Rats.class).list();//  new HashSet<Rats>();
                Set<Rats> sickRatsSet = new HashSet<Rats>();
                for(Rats rat : sickratsList){
                    sickRatsSet.add(rat);
                }
                sickness2.setRatses(sickRatsSet);
                session.save(sickness2);
```

Debuging this shows that the Sickness is correctly inserted into the DB, its sickRatsSet field is correctly set with all the rats.
But... if I check the Rats status, their Sickness has not been updated.

Trying to set CascadeType. into the Sickness relationship did not help.

I know that I could solve it with something like:

```
ArrayList<Rats> sickratsList =  (ArrayList<Rats>) session.createCriteria(Rats.class).list();//  new HashSet<Rats>();
Set<Rats> sickRatsSet = new HashSet<Rats>();
for(Rats rat : sickratsList){
    rat.setSickness(seckness2);
    session.save(rat);
```

}

But I would like to understand how to do it via Sickness.setRatses.
So that I can find my way later with a many to many relationship (I suppose it will be pretty similar).

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 2):

A bidirectional association has an *owner* side (the side *without* the `mappedBy` attribute), and an *inverse* side (the side *with* the `mappedBy` attribute).

Hibernate only considers the *owner* side when deciding which entities are associated with each other.

Adding rats to a sickness thus won't make Hibernate associate the rat to the sickness, since that only modifies the inverse side. You **must** set the rat's sickness.

Note that using a DELETE cascade on a ManyToXxx annotation doesn't make much sense. There is no reason to delete the tourista sickness from the database as soon as one of the thousand rats having the tourista is deleted. And that will obviously cause an exception anyway, since 999 other rats have a foreign key to the tourista sickness.

Comment: isn't that only applicable for ManyToMany associations? The question mentions only a bidirectional ManyToOne.

Comment: No. It's applicable to all bidirectional associations.

Comment: Strange, I just tested it using Hibernate (4.2), and just setting the association from the inverse side on a ManyToOne association does persist the data fine (as long as the cascade is configured on `PERSIST`). The only place I know that has problems with only setting associations on the inverse side are ManyToMany associations.

Comment: Then your test must be flawed. You're probably following your own, good advice and setting the owner side when setting the inverse side. I just tested it again, to be absolutely sure, on a OneToMany with cascade ALL, and I get an exception due to non-null constraint violated, or the entity is saved but without its FK being populated if I drop the non-null constraint.

Comment: And anyway, even if Hibernate did do that, the JPA spec explicitely says that the owner side must be populated.

Comment: Phew, we are in agreement there :). Hibernate must be doing something outside the spec (as usual :), which allows this to work. I've created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e942c4f5adff2c66e21b) with my test, but I don't want to completely hijack this question. - Thanks!

Comment: Your test is incorrect. It tests that the account is persisted, and that the person is persisted. They are. What is not persisted is the association between both. The B_retrieve test should test that the account's person is not null and equal to the created person, and that the person's accounts contains 1 element: the created account.

Comment: Sometimes I surprise myself (in a bad way). Thanks a lot for the insight!

Answer (score 1):

This error happens because you're retrieving the objects that are already cached in the 1st level cache (session), and those objects don't have the bidirectional association set correctly. In your code, you're never calling `rat.setSickeness(sickness)`.

Try calling the following methods and check if the data is now correct

```
session.flush()
session.clear()
// load the rats /sickness again and the relations should be set.
```

Bottom line: when you have a bidirectional association is the developer responsibility to add/set the objects on boths ends, otherwise you'll get into this error. The simplest way to fix this is to only have one method in one of your 2 objects that know how to maintain the assocation. For example

```
public class Rat {
   public void setSickness(Sickness sickness) {
      this.sicknesses = sickness;
      sickness.addRat(this);
   }
}

public class Sickness {
   // leave this as package protected! So the only way to set the association is from the Rat
   void addRat(Rat rat) {
      rats.add(rat);
   }
}
```

You might want to read the Hibernate documentation about Session and how it works as a 1st level cache.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks JB and Augusto, I got a much better understanding now.

I was able to solve my issue by overriding this way:

```
public void setRatses(Set<Rats> ratses) {
        this.ratses = ratses; 
        for(Rats rat : ratses){
            rat.setSickness(this);
        }
```

This bring me another methodological question.

I found out that if I do the following:
raton.setSickness(sickness1);
raton.display(); -> raton.sickness = sickness1 as expected
sickness1.display(); -> sickness1.ratses does not contain raton for the reasons that you guys pointed.

I can either use session.flush()
session.clear() or commit the transaction and start a new one if I need  sickness1.ratses to be up to date.

I suppose that I can also override Rats.setSickness this way:

```
public void setSickness(Sickness sickness) {
        if(sickness.ratses.contain(this) sickness.ratses.remove(this);
        this.sickness = sickness; 
        ickness.ratses.add(this);
    }
```

this way, my sickness is up to date inside the session without I need to flush the session.

Would this be such a good idea?
On regarding performance side, I suppose that the override solution generates additional DB operations that might not be really needed?